# Why quotes in attribute name raise an error?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

When I execute a file with node.js containing **only** `{"test":1}`, a SyntaxError is raised :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { {"test":1}
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

But `{test:1}` (without quotes) or `var t = {"test":1}` works fine.

I execute the file containing the code running : `node test.js`.

Why ?

Comment: Could you provide some more context? where are you declaring that object?

Comment: That is all that is in the file? How are you "executing" it?

Comment: yes, there is only this in the file. I execute it with `node mytest.js`

Comment: MDN [Block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: @epascarello, Oooooh you're probably right ! But the interpreter can't recognize the object ?

Comment: It makes not sense why you would try to run an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` forms a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

`test:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which is valid (but pointless since there is no loop).

`"test":` is a string, followed by a colon, which is nonsense.

`var foo = {}` puts the `{}` in a different context, so they form an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) instead of a block. Inside an object literal, property names can be identifiers or strings.

---

Your `test.js` content looks like JSON, not JavaScript. It makes no sense to execute it because it doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: also parentheses will "fix" this

Comment: The relevant part of ES5 is [section 12.4](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4).